# Why is the forecolor change on Mouseover event is slower than backcolor mouseover change in the properties setting??

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a button mouseover event to change both the forecolor and backcolor at the same time by choosing the Mouseoverbackcolor setting from properties and by writing the code for forecolor(since i can't find the event setting in properties for forecolor).But the problem is that the forecolor setting is about half a second slow when i hover the mouseover the button.I got curious and tried writing the backcolor mouseover event manually and now both of them are slow.Why is that and is there anyway to fix it?

```
 private void btnfirearm_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnfirearm.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; 
    }

    private void btnfirearm_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bfirearm == true)
        { btnfirearm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(66, 131, 222);
        btnfirearm.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
        else
        { btnfirearm.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black; }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is the MouseHover event. It only gets raised after `MouseHoverTime` has elapsed.

Comment: So does it mean that the MouseHoverEvent took longer than MouseOverEvent in the properties setting. I thought they are both the same.

Comment: There is no MouseOver event in WinForms, so I have no idea what you're talking about. What you should be using is the MouseEnter event.

Comment: It is a hack, the Button class already uses MouseEnter to change colors.  So the MouseHover event *seems* like a workaround.  It is not, it is slow to be generated.  You must instead derive your own class from Button and override OnMouseEnter() to do your own thing.

Comment: The one inside Propeties---FlatAppearance--MouseOverBackColor

Comment: Thanks,it's working with MouseEnter event now.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried messing with the Tooltip initialdelay and it is working now.